# Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id _NonNull' with an lvalue of type double

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Objective C:

I have multiple variables of type double, long long, NSString and int which I want to put in an array to be printed as a single line in a CSV file

NSArray *ValArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: var1, var2, var3 , var4, var5, nil];

Here var1 is of type double and var2,var3 are of the type long long.

This gives me a syntax error saying that "Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id _NonNull' with an lvalue of type double" at var1

I'm a newbie in Objective C and unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The contents of `NSArray` (and `NSDictionary`) in Objective-C must be objects. All scalar types `int` `double` etc. are not objects.

There is an easy solution:

Wrap all scalar types in the shortcut `NSNumber` initializer `@()`

```
 double var1 = 12.0;
 NSString *var2 = @"Foo";
 NSArray *valArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @(var1), var2, nil];
```

or still shorter

```
 NSArray *valArray = @[@(var1), var2];
```

To get the `double` type back from the array you have to write

```
 double var3 = valArray[0].doubleValue;
```

Side note: Variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

Convert var1, var2, var3 to NSNumber will resolve it.