# Cast c vector of shared_ptr to NSArray objectiveC

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, vector, casting

i have a vector of shared_ptr:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Element>> vector
```

I need to cast it to a NSArray, I've tried this way:

```
 _arrayDataSource = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:&vector[0] count:vector.size()];
```

but it give me this error:

> Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id  _Nonnull const __unsafe_unretained * _Nonnull' with an rvalue of type 'std::__1::__vector_base, std::__1::allocator > >::value_type *' (aka 'std::__1::shared_ptr *')

Is there a better way to cast the vector of shared_ptr to NSArray?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id \_NonNull' with an lvalue of type double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46884265/cannot-initialize-a-parameter-of-type-id-nonnull-with-an-lvalue-of-type-doubl)

Comment: Actually no, the problem is completely different, the error is from one of the solution i've tried and not the problem itself

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: Wouldnt you need a NSArray with Element like objects, which you can loop through by dereferencing the shared_ptr objects and assigning to NSArray elements ?

Comment: yes, I need to cast a vector of shared_ptr to a NSArray